# How to add a column/feature with PyQGIS 2.x?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, error, qgs

I'm using PyQgis 2.2 and I'm creating a plugin.
I want to add one feature/column to a shapefile. But I get error..

I've tried to do this as it's shown in Cookbook:

```
 if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddFeatures:
     feat = QgsFeature()
     feat.addAttribute(0,"hello")
     feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(123,456)))
     (res, outFeats) = layer.dataProvider().addFeatures( [ feat ] )
```

but I only get error:

```
 AttributeError: 'QgsFeature' object has no attribute 'addAttribute'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are reading an old version of the PyQGIS Cookbook.

Try with the `addAttributes` method of the layer provider, as indicated in the latest [PyQGIS Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#adding-and-removing-fields). Specifically:

```
if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddFeatures:
    res = layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("id",  QVariant.Int), QgsField("mytext", QVariant.String)])
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(123,456)))
    feat.setAttributes([0, "hello"])
    (resAddFeat, outFeats) = layer.dataProvider().addFeatures( [ feat ] )
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply ! I tried it, but I get a new error "NameError: name 'QVariant' is not defined" (I used Console Python)

Comment: Add this to the import section of your Python file: `from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant`